# how to get gps location android

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to have a constant gps listener that will send its location (long and lat coordinates) to a web server every x mins. On a button click it will also send its location to the webserver. I realize that to get the gps signal you type in how often to find a position, but how do I write a program that can get the gps location and send its coordinates every x mins (even in the background when not and by a button press?

//in the on click

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, whatshouldIputhere?, 0, this);
```

and

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use a higher-level API that has a simpler interface and comes with additional features: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

Comment: check that out https://github.com/meetmehdi/GetAccurateLocation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've got this working:

```
private void _getLocation() {
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }
}
```

It's simple. It gets the best available provider and gets its last known position.

If you want it only with the GPS, try [this](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/android-localizacion-1.zip).

Hope it helps!

### EDITED:

try this:

```
private void _getLocation() {
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, loc_listener);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }
}
```

This code gets the last known location and then do a request for the actual location.

Comment: Hi, Im currently using this method for my update on button click. Can you tell me why the location that it gives me is around 2blocks away from where I actually am? I've tried this 5 times and I keep getting the same location

Comment: this method returns the last known location, if you want to get the location when you are running the method, you have to request it. I edited my answer, check it please

Comment: My code runs in an async task, when I put in the edited code I was forced to put in looper.prepare() above locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,0,0,loc_listener); After doing this my program still sends out the same (incorrect) gps signal.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use `Timer` and `TimerTask`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SendLocationTask(), 0, 60000);

class SendLocationTask extends TimerTask{
    public abstract void run(){
        // send position info here
    }
}
```

Comment: will this timer class continue to do work at 60000s intervals even when the app is running in the background and even when someone is using another app? eg: continuously posting where you are unless you turn off background updates for this app

Comment: It depends on where you put this piece of code. If you put it in a `Service` then yes it should work in the background, until `stopService()` is explicitly called

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods you could use. You could use a separate [thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) that waits for x minutes and then sends the latest known location to the server. Or you use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that does more or less the same. As a third possibility you could also use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a thread that will run in background and every x minutes you get the actual position by calling a function that does that (Note that you want to make a function that get the x,y coordinates since you will use that on button click aswel). For the code you posted :

```
locationManager.requestUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, intent);
```

That means that your application will send a request to gps module every x min for the whatshouldIputhere?

Good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me (api 17)

```
try {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();


    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```