# Pending Intent from Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    lmgr.addProximityAlert(lati,longi,radius,-1, pendingIntent);

<receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver"></receiver>
```

I want to listen for location in android, but the pending intent is not working. I've tried the above code & used getService() as well. But no luck. Kindly Guide me in right direction.

Comment: What are the values of `lati`, `longi` and `radius` when you make the call? Have you checked the (unfiltered) logcat to see if any errors or other useful messages appear? Are you sure `LocationReceiver.onReceive()` is not being called?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declared the intent-filters for this receiver? Make sure for that. And also add the Location related permissions in your manifest.

Comment: why would I need intent filter? and I have declared location permissions.

Comment: To receive the call to onReceive() method.. Any how, once try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157927/how-to-get-gps-location-android