# capturing location from smartphone on PC - Java

Tags: java, android, geolocation, smartphone

I am writing a java program on my laptop/desktop computer in which I need my current location.

To best of my knowledge there are three way to get my current location. 
1) my IP Address
2) USB GPS receiver connected to my latop
3) From my Andriod Smartphone

The first two option is not problem for me. But can some one guide how can I use smartphone gps receiver for the said purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get gps location android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157927/how-to-get-gps-location-android)

Comment: that is sending coordinates to web server. My question is to send coordinates to computer directly from mobile phone via data cable , Bluetooth.