# How to get user location without gps or wifi?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

how to get the user location without gps? I mean using the data services or network. Is it possible? Can anyone please give any sample code to look at on that?

Comment: how about https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: There are lots of examples on Internet. Just Search it on Google.

Comment: I went there. But i couldnt get my answer. Thats y asking your help.

Comment: Most of them are using GPS and the bestprovider. But i want to get the location without gps.

Comment: Then ask specifically for the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my stripped down Location Service I am using right now. GPS and Network are called Providers in this context.

I've changed the way my logic works, where it checks which provider is enabled and then returns the best one that's enabled (GPS is better then network), to this line: String providerToSend = providers.get(1);, in the GetProvider method.
So instead of checking each provider, this way it chooses providers.get(1), which is always the string NETWORK. Feed that to your locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TheStringWithTheCorrectProviderGoesHere), and it'll return your position.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;


public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public String providerNow;
    private List<String> providers;

    public Location location;
    private final Context mContext;


    public LocationService(Context context) {
        Log.i("TestMap", "LocationService");


        this.mContext = context;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);

        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }



    public Location getLocation() {

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerNow);
        return location;
    }


    public String GetProvider (){

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(2);

        providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        String providerToSend = providers.get(1);

        return providerToSend;

    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TestMap", "onBind");
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Location locationNew = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us a line where you call this service from activity, since it is saying that it doesnt have empty constructor and my app crashes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android stores last location, u can get it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Many examples first read lastKnown then looks more data from providers [how to get gps location android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157927/how-to-get-gps-location-android)

Comment: BUt it says how to get "gps" location... Not without gps.